# pg_dump: how to install on Amazon Linux for PostgreSQL 9.5.2?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, rds

I used to install and do:

```
$ sudo yum install -y postgresql94-server postgresql94
$ pg_dump -h name-of-db.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U user dbName > dump
```

After RDS upgrade to 9.5.2 I get this:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.5.2; pg_dump version: 9.4.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

I can't find a proper package for Amazon Linux

This didn't help me: http://tecadmin.net/install-postgresql-9-5-on-centos/

Can you?

Answer (score 23):

Ok, found it.

(1) Install the repo:

```
$ sudo rpm -Uvh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-95-9.5-3.noarch.rpm
```

- Update: 9.5.2-> 9.5.3
Found the repo [here](http://tecadmin.net/install-postgresql-9-5-on-centos/).

(2) Then install the package:

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql95
```

Now you can dump your RDS database to a near by ec2 instance!

Comment: In order for me to get this to work I first copied the proper link from https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php. Then I had to uninstall my existing postgres `sudo yum remove postgresql92` before installing the new one.

Answer (score 23):

You can actually install a newer version of Postgres with the Amazon Extras Library: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library

I needed Postgres 10, so for me the command was:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql10
```

You can view a list of extras Amazon Linux provides by using this command:

```
amazon-linux-extras list
```

Comment: amazon-linux-extras is available fro Amazon Linux 2 only

Comment: Thanks! For Postgres 11, simply change to `sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql11`

Comment: I know it is super late, but this became useful for me and might come in handly for others -> sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql11 (just now :) )