# libpcre.so.0 missing on AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum, amazon-ami

I recently installed PostgreSQL Server at my AWS AMI EC2 instance.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881350/pg-dump-how-to-install-on-amazon-linux-for-postgresql-9-5-2/36888416#36888416) to guide me through the right RPM package.

Everything is working fine, however, now when I try to install Postgis with `sudo yum install postgis23_95.x86_64` I receive:

```
Error: Package: postgis23_95-2.3.7-1.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg95)
Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
```

I cannot manage to fix this error. I also tried `sudo yum install pcre-tools.x86_64`, but nothing changed.